# Falsifiability of nutcase theories that rest upon sensible theories

Tags: philosophy-of-science, falsifiability

My friend has a theory that [invisible pink unicorns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invisible_Pink_Unicorn) are orbiting Earth. I claim that according to Karl Popper's [falsifiability criterion](https://www.britannica.com/topic/criterion-of-falsifiability), this theory is not scientific as it is not falsifiable. My friend retorts: "Sure it is! My theory rests on the theory of gravitation, as gravity is what makes objects orbit Earth. If the theory of gravitation is falsified, then my theory is falsified. Thus my theory is falsifiable, and therefore scientific."

Is my friend's argument valid?

Comment: Your friends argument also relies on the premise that not only do unicorns exist, but that they are pink. I'd also say it relies on the premise those unicorns can survive the vacuum, cold, and radiation of space... but they didn't claim they were alive.

Comment: He is half right. Pink invisibility aside, since the unicorns are apparently postulated to have mass they can, in principle, be detected from gravitational influence on other bodies (just like dark matter). Falsifiability is one condition for a scientific theory to be worth consideration, but it sure isn't sufficient. Another one is that it should actually be useful for explaining something else.

Comment: Hm... Can an invisible object be said to have a color?

Comment: @TedWrigley: Sure, with an [alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) of zero (which maps to full transparency).

Answer (score 3):

I've heard it said that string theory isn't falsifiable, and so should not be regarded as science (in my amateur opinion, this argument is not good since falsifiability is not the only criterion of science or rationality, but never mind that). If what your friend is saying is correct, then string theory *is* falsifiable; all you need to do is falsify quantum mechanics or relativity, for example. But this isn't what people usually mean by calling a theory falsifiable.

When people say that a theory is falsifiable, I'm pretty sure they mean something like this: Let S be the conjunction of all currently accepted scientific theories, and let T be some additional theory not contained in S. To say T is falsifiable means T *and* S imply new observations that weren't implied by S alone, and those new observations are testable and could, for all we know, turn out to be false. (Of course, this makes falsifiability relative to moments in time, since S is always changing, but this is fine; some things are testable today that were not testable in the past. And presumably there are some things that we cannot test today that we may be able to test in the future.)

Returning to your friend's invisible pink unicorn theory, we should ask him what *new* falsifiable predictions his theory (T) makes that were not already implied by our theory of gravity (S).

Answer (score 1):

***tl;dr*–**  Yes, your friend's theory is marginally falsifiable and therefore marginally "*scientific*", where "*scientific*" means "*prone to scientific scrutiny*".  Of course, this doesn't mean that it's *correct*, nor is its falsifiable surface area particularly interesting.

---

> My friend retorts: "Sure it is! My theory rests on the theory of gravitation, as gravity is what makes objects orbit Earth. If the theory of gravitation is falsified, then my theory is falsified. Thus my theory is falsifiable, and therefore scientific."

Yeah, sure, this is accurate-ish (ignoring the necessary-but-not-sufficient issue).

To be clear, when we say that theories must be falsifiable to be scientific, what we mean is that theories must be falsifiable to be prone to scientific analysis.  Your friend's theory is marginally falsifiable, and so it's marginally prone to scientific scrutiny.  For example, as your friend correctly notes, their theory could be falsified if gravity is disproven.

Of course, a theory being scientific (i.e., prone to scientific scrutiny) doesn't make it correct.

Nor does a theory being scientific (in the sense of being prone to scientific scrutiny) make it scientific (in the sense of being verified by scientific analysis).

Also, we're currently looking for such [invisible-but-gravitational unicorns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter).

---

#### Note:  "*Scientific*" means something different from normal here.

Folks probably think of "*scientific*" theories as those supported by scientific research.

In the context of falsifiability, "*scientific*" means "*able to be scrutinized by scientific research*".

For example, say Alice asserts that Luna is, in fact, made of cheese – a fine white cheddar, to be precise.  Then:

1. Alice's theory is "*scientific*" in the sense of it being prone to scientific analysis.
2. Alice's theory is ***not*** "*scientific*" in the sense of being supported by scientific analysis.

---

#### Note:  There's a framing ambiguity complicating the situation.

Consider a student handing in their homework:

> **Student:**  Here's my research paper!
> [*The teacher glances over the paper.*]
> **Teacher:**  This was supposed to be a *referenced* research paper, but I don't see a single citation!
> **Student:**  Check out the cover page!  I cited my birth certificate, state ID, passport, *and* social-security card to reference my name, giving me 4 authoritative sources!

Is the student's paper "*referenced*"?

Yes, it is!  The student did include references, so the overall paper is, in fact, referenced.

That said, the teacher's likely to be unimpressed as the significant bulk of the paper isn't referenced, despite the totality of it being referenced.

Likewise, your friend's theory about invisible pink unicorns has a significant bulk of it that may be unfalsifiable.  So while your friend may correctly point out that the totality is falsifiable, this isn't a defense against the observation that a good bulk of it isn't.

---

#### Note:  Falsifiability is a very low bar.

Unfalsifiable theories have also been called ["*not even wrong*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong).

We say that they're "*not even*" wrong because being unfalsifiable is worse than merely being wrong.  Wrong theories were at least meaningful enough to get to the point where they could be called wrong; by contrast, not-even-wrong theories fail to even get that far.

Answer (score 0):

First, to clarify that's a hypothesis, not a scientific theory. The reason why I think that argument sounds off is because evidence for or against a scientific hypothesis is usually of the sufficient and necessary nature. For example if I think protein A allows an organism to eat chemical B then I support the hypothesis by removing the protein and demonstrating how the cell no longer eats chemical B (it is necessary), the sufficient case is obvious because it does grow when it has the protein and I can go the extra mile and show that it catalyzes the reaction etc. In this case gravity is necessary for the hypothesized creature to exist, but not sufficient (gravity existing doesn't imply the creature existing) so it's not convincing evidence and doesn't show falsifiability (not that I think science is defined by falsifiability).